# Query user Inactivity & give opportunity to continue session - Android

Tags: android

I'm wondering could you help me with a query i'm struggling with. I have created a full page android app webview for my website. What i am looking to do is:

Once the user walks away from the tablet, after 30 seconds i want the app to popup with the query "Are you still here?" with a "Yes" option. If yes is pressed then they continue their session. If nothing is pressed then the app is refreshed.

I have tried using a timed disconnect but it doesn't give me the popup option as it just disconnects the session.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: "disconnect handler"? what is it?

Comment: Apologies, explained it in a rush - I meant a timed disconnect where after x amount of time the session ends.

Comment: use a Handler.postDelayed() for delayed action execution

Comment: Never used that actually. You have an example?

Comment: on the right side of this page is a "Related" section, check it

Comment: Unfortunately have looked through all threads and have not had much luck. I'll continue to do what i can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the second one, with number 34